# How do I parent redirect visitors to another page if page inside iframe loaded 8 times?

Tags: javascript

I have embedded a webpage inside iframe and want to parent redirect visitors to another webpage if the page inside iframe has been loaded 8 times? Any idea how to do it?

I can redirect every time when the iframe page load with the following codes.

```
function replaceLoad(oIframe) {
    oIframe.onload = function () {
    location.href = 'www.google.com'
    }
}

<iframe id="xMyIframe" src="url" onload="replaceLoad(this)">
</iframe>
```

How can I modify it to suit my purpose?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var times = 0;
    function iframechange() {
        times++;
        if( times > 8 ){
            window.location.href = "http://google.com";
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <iframe onload="iframechange();" src="http://example.com/"></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```